# iOS Threading Violations Detection?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, concurrent-programming

On iOS, I am wondering if there is anything akin to the NSZombies flag that can be set to detect/raise when a call is made to an API from a background thread when the main thread is required.

With blocks, it seems to be easy to get into a situation where one either makes false assumptions or mistakes about which thread is doing what. A debugging flag that could detect when a call is made from the wrong thread would be really useful for finding these cases.

It is primarily Apple's frameworks that concern me (Cocoa Touch).

Filed a bug report, #12180446.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following in any API of yours that requires being on the main thread:

```
NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"This must only be called on the main thread.");
```

Apple does not provide such a thing that covers all of UIKit. You will need to call it when you need it.

Comment: Yes, but it's up to you to check prior to calling them. There is no global UIKit-level assertion available. If you believe you need one, you should open a radar at bugreport.apple.com. It is unlikely that they would add it, since it would require hooks all over the place (incurring runtime costs in the simplest implementation, and being very complicated to maintain in the no-cost implementation). But the way you request things is though bugreport.apple.com. In the meantime, it is up to you to add this assertion where you need it.

Comment: I think the same argument could be made against supporting things like NSZombies. Apple is investing a lot of effort into enhancing developer tools and lowering the bar by eliminating issues such as memory management (ARC), subtle coding errors (static analyzer), enhancing compiler messages, etc. Having an ability to catch when a call is being made from a background thread to an API that requires the main thread would be pretty useful. Apple is clever. I'll bet that they can figure out a way that's not onerous.

Comment: Make sure to post your radar at openradar.appspot.com so others can dupe it.

Answer (score 1):

I do something more practical. when I call blocks. I do it with a custom method.

```
+ (void) ensureDispatchOfBlock:(dispatch_block_t) block onQueue:(dispatch_queue_t) queue  async:(BOOL) async{
    if (queue == nil || dispatch_get_current_queue() == queue){
        block();
    }
    else {
        if (async){
            dispatch_async(queue, block);
        }
        else {
            dispatch_sync(queue, block);
        }
    }
}


+ (void) ensureDispatchOnMainThread:(dispatch_block_t) block async:(BOOL) async{
    [self ensureDispatchOfBlock:block onQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue() async:async];
}
```

This allows me to "Ensure" the dispatch of the block being provided is going to happen on the block it was intended.

Just remember to use `async:NO` very sparingly.